# Better way to map tokens to enum values?

Tags: java, enums, antlr, antlr3

I'm trying to have my parser rule select an enum value based on my `DIR` token. Is there a way I can do this without creating separate, full-fledged tokens for each direction? Or generally a cleaner approach?

```
DIR : (NORTH|SOUTH) (EAST|WEST)?
 | EAST
 | WEST;

fragment NORTH: N '.'? | N O R T H;
fragment SOUTH: S '.'? | S O U T H;
fragment EAST : E '.'? | E A S T;
fragment WEST : W '.'? | W E S T;
```

(there are token fragments for each letter to facilitate case-insensitivity)

The enum is `public enum Direction {    NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST, NORTHEAST, NORTHWEST, SOUTHEAST, SOUTHWEST }`

Right now the only solution I see is to convert `DIR` to a parser rule and make the directions separate tokens:

```
NORTH: N '.'? | N O R T H;
SOUTH: S '.'? | S O U T H;

dir returns [Direction dir]
 : NORTH { dir = Direction.NORTH; }
 | SOUTH { dir = Direction.SOUTH; }
```

This isn't *terrible* for this scenario, but I've got some other enums that will have lots more options so I'm looking for any ways to simplify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with ANTLR, but from a fast scan of the docs it seems to work pretty much like yacc/racc and it seems to allow arbitrary methods to be defined in an `@member` block, so I would expect you can use something like:

```
dir returns [Direction dir]
: DIR { $result = directionStringToEnum($DIR.text); }
```

where you have to define a separate

```
public Direction directionStringToEnum(String dir) {
   Direction.valueOf(dir.toUpperCase());
}
```

in the `@member` block. You may be able to generalize that to handle arbitrary enums (but probable in any ugly way, requiring Class.forName()).

Comment: The problem is that for the south-west token, the inner text of it (`$DIR.text`) could be `"SWesT"`, `"S.W."`, `"southw"`, ...

Comment: That's an angle I hadn't though of, but by itself I'm not sure it helps. `Direction.valueOf('North')` would work but `Direction.valueOf('N')`  will result in an `IllegalArgumentException` the way things are set up.

Comment: Perhaps there is a helper function, like the .text, that gives you the name of the `fragment`? From the stuff [here](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Special+symbols+in+actions) it seems you may be able to get at all kinds of properties of the current token

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to rewrite the inner text of the tokens so they match your enum values. In your parser, you could then do `Direction.valueOf(String)` to parse it into a real enum.

Something like this:

```
...

parse
  :  (
       DIR {System.out.println("enum=" + Direction.valueOf($DIR.text));}
     )* 
     EOF
  ;

DIR
  :  ( NORTH {setText("NORTH");}      | SOUTH {setText("SOUTH");}      ) 
     ( EAST  {setText($text+"EAST");} | WEST  {setText($text+"WEST");} )?
  |  EAST {setText("EAST");}
  |  WEST {setText("WEST");}     
  ;

...
```

The following test:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String src = "N EaSt S. w NE N.w. Southe SWeSt";
    CompassLexer lexer = new CompassLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(src));
    CompassParser parser = new CompassParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.parse();
  }
}
```

produced:

```
java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool Compass.g 
javac -cp antlr-3.3.jar *.java
java -cp .:antlr-3.3.jar Main

enum=NORTH
enum=EAST
enum=SOUTH
enum=WEST
enum=NORTHEAST
enum=NORTHWEST
enum=SOUTHEAST
enum=SOUTHWEST
```

It's a bit clunky, perhaps. But if you're going to construct tokens from (many) different tokens (like with South-West or North-East), it may shorten your grammar opposed to something like:

```
dir returns [Direction dir]
 : NORTH { dir = Direction.NORTH; }
 | SOUTH { dir = Direction.SOUTH; }
 ...
 ;
```

Comment: `setText` is a trick I'd forgotten about. Do you see any reason to prefer having the single `DIR` token vs. all the separate direction tokens?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the idea in [Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16784/confusion)'s comment, I did track down a way to get the token names. So if I make a token for each direction I should be able to do something like:

```
dir returns [Direction dir]
 : (d=NORTH | d=SOUTH | d=EAST | d=WEST | d=NORTHEAST | d=NORTHWEST | d=SOUTHEAST | d=SOUTHWEST )
   { dir = Direction.valueOf(getTokenNames()[$d.getType()]); }

NORTH: N '.'? | N O R T H;
SOUTH: S '.'? | S O U T H;
EAST:  E '.'? | E A S T;
WEST:  W '.'? | W E S T;
NORTHEAST : N E | N '.' E '.' | N O R T H E A S T;
NORTHWEST : N W | N '.' W '.' | N O R T H W E S T;
SOUTHEAST : S E | S '.' E '.' | S O U T H E A S T;
SOUTHWEST : S W | S '.' W '.' | S O U T H W E S T;
```

This will mean a lot more tokens, but really cuts down on the typing.

I also tried to combine it this with Bart's suggestion, but it appears that `state.type` isn't set during the lexing phase (it results in NullPointerException). The lexer does assign type IDs to fragments, there just doesn't seem to be any way to access them from a lexer rule.

```
main_rule[CustomObject object]: d=DIR ...
           { object.setDirection(Direction.valueof($d.text)); };

DIR
 : (NORTH | SOUTH | EAST| WEST | NORTHEAST | NORTHWEST | SOUTHEAST | SOUTHWEST)
   { setText(getTokenNames()[state.type]);

fragment NORTH: N '.'? | N O R T H;
...
```